# Can't receive data(sent from c# application) in my node.js server

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, sockets

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is wrong with my code and I know there is a lot of information out there but non of it seems to fix my problem.

I managed to received data from UNITY application but it doesn't work from c#.

This is my Node.js server code:

```
var server = require('http').createServer()
    , url = require('url')
    , WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
    , wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server })
    , express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , port = 8080;

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.send({ msg: "hello" });
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
   console.log('received: %s', message);
});
 ws.send('Trying to send information');
});
```

This is my c# code:
This is how I connect:

```
 private  void Connect()
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("***********"), 8080);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                lb_stt.Text = ("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
            }
        }
        lb_stt.Text = ("Connected!");
    }
```

This is how I send data

```
    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            //IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.186.139.115"), 8080);
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("check");
                int its = _clientSocket.Send(buffer);
                MessageBox.Show((its.ToString()));//Output:5 This shows that my C# code apparently sends the data
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                //_clientSocket.Disconnect(true);
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

I have very basic understanding of Node.js, so I apologize if the question is easy.

The problem is that when I clicked the button in c# I can't receive the information in my node.js server, although I connect to the server in the c# application..

Another question is if I want to stream data from a sensor should I still use ws.send or ws.broadcast? (https://github.com/websockets/ws)

Comment: Why you didn't use `port` variable in Node.js server initialization?

Comment: I don't know Node.js very much. But it seems that you're using a WebSocket server in your Node.js code, but a Winsock socket in your C# code. If that is the case, your server will certainly not receive any data. You should use a WebSocket client(e.g. the `ClientWebSocket` class) in your C# code.

Comment: Stalker is probably going the right direction - `websocket != socket`.

Comment: @Stalker Thanks. I think you are right! I will give at try and I will ask if I have any more problems